# How to create a prompt/answer system in R?

Tags: r

I saw in the thread 'Creating a Prompt/Answer system to input data into R' that it is possible to Let R respond to questions. I would like to do the same but based on my dataframe.

My dataframe looks like the following:

| PP | Trait |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |

I basically would like to let R answer the following questions:

- Did participants score at least 1 on Trait? Y/N
- Did participants score at least 2 on Trait? Y/N
- Did participants score at least 3 on Trait? Y/N

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `svDialogs` - package might provide what you need. You can create Dialog- and Input-Boxes with it that return the entered values wich you can later process within your script.

Link: [svDialogs on Github](https://github.com/SciViews/svDialogs)